# re.findall playing favorites in pipes when surrounded by greedy wildcards

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm having trouble understanding how Python 3.8 treats regexes when trying to match multiple patterns using the `|` operator.  It seems like the regex "plays favorites" and only selects certain patterns over others when deciding what to capture. I thought it had to do with how patterns are ordered, but order appears to have zero effect on either what gets returned or what order they get returned in. Obviously it's somewhere in the wildcards, but it still doesn't quite make sense to me.

The following (heavily abstracted) script shows where I'm not understanding things:

```
import re

sentence = 'This is neither a long nor a difficult string to parse'

# Scenario 1: no patterns at the beginning"
long_first = re.compile(r'(long|difficult)')
difficult_first = re.compile(r'(difficult|long)')
print(re.findall(long_first, sentence)) # -> ['long', 'difficult']
print(re.findall(difficult_first, sentence)) # -> ['long', 'difficult']

# Scenario 2: .+ at the beginning
long_first = re.compile(r'.+(long|difficult)')
difficult_first = re.compile(r'.+(difficult|long)')
print(re.findall(long_first, sentence)) # -> ['difficult']
print(re.findall(difficult_first, sentence)) # -> ['difficult']

# Scenario 3: .+ at the end
long_first = re.compile(r'(long|difficult).+')
difficult_first = re.compile(r'(difficult|long).+')
print(re.findall(long_first, sentence)) # -> ['long']
print(re.findall(difficult_first, sentence)) # -> ['long']

# Scenario 4: .+ at the end and the beginning
long_first = re.compile(r'.+(long|difficult).+')
difficult_first = re.compile(r'.+(difficult|long).+')
print(re.findall(long_first, sentence)) # -> ['difficult']
print(re.findall(difficult_first, sentence)) # -> ['difficult']
```

Why are the results not consistently `['long', 'difficult']`? And why does scenario 3 not return `['difficult']`?

Comment: A greedy repetition in a regex will *immediately* gobble up everything that matches, all the way to the end of the string if possible.  If this causes a subsequent portion of the regex to fail, it will back up, one repetition at a time, until a match can be found.  If a complete match *is* found, then no further backup will even be considered, the greedy repetition has done its job.  (As for scenarios 3 & 4: having `.+` at the end means that the match will extend all the way to the end of the string, leaving nothing to be searched for the next iteration of `.findall()`.)

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for the help.

Comment: The question is more or less language-agnostic; while there are a few flavours of regex out there, I've never heard of one that treated `.+` differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching goes from left-to-right, so in the pattern `.+(long|difficult).+` the first `.+` matches as much as it possibly can while still allowing the rest of the expression to match.

This means that the pattern `.+(long|difficult).+` finds the *last* place in the sentence where one of the two words appears.

To understand it better, also try the patterns on the sentence:

```py
'This is neither a difficult nor a long string to parse'
```